# How can I get the computer name to display in the return along with the serial number without writing it twice?

Tags: powershell

(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_BIOS -ComputerName $computername).SerialNumber

I would like a way to return the computer name along with it, without having to type in the computer name twice.

I've found a couple different ways to return the computer name, but all have required my typing it in twice.

Comment: Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_BIOS-ComputerName $computername | Select-object -Property Name, SerialNumber

Comment: -Property Name is returning the same result as SMBIOSBIOSVersion, not the computer name. '(get-wmiobject Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $computername).username ' gives me what I'm looking for, how can I incorporate that?

Comment: the -Property parameters in my solution are an array and can be changed as needed.

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you want is to receive an object with three (or more) properties and in this case I would use a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties):

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $computername |
Select-Object @{Name = 'ComputerName'; Expression = {$_.Name}}, SerialNumber, UserName
```

By the way, [WMI is being deprecated](https://www.ipswitch.com/blog/get-ciminstance-vs-get-wmiobject-whats-the-difference), so I have used the newer `Get-CimInstance` instead

Answer (score 0):

When remoting in PowerShell, the property `PSComputerName` is added so..

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_BIOS -ComputerName $ComputerName |
  select PSComputerName, SerialNumber
```

And as @Theo stated, don't use `WMI` where possible.